# What happens to a flag when the community deletes the post before it's actioned?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, flagging, deleted-answers

I flagged [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13323/732) as offensive, and then voted to delete it. Then, before the flag was acted on by a mod, other members of the community voted to delete the post, and it was deleted.

Looking at my flagging summary, there is no indication that it was actioned, or marked "helpful" or otherwise, nor did my flag weight increase.

So, what happened? Was my flag automatically deleted when the post was? Did it just not get marked "helpful" for whatever reason?

If the latter, should flagged posts be automatically marked as "helpful" when the post gets deleted (by the mods or the community)?

Very much related, but not a duplicate of [I'm not gaining flag weight for my Spam flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109100/im-not-gaining-flag-weight-for-my-spam-flags)

Comment: I suspect that the community's deletion of the post constitutes a ratification of your flag, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: If the community acted to delete a post without anybody actually looking at your flag, was the flag helpful?  It was *correct*, but that's different.

Comment: @Monica. True, but I suspect your reading it more literally than it was meant :) (although I could be wrong). See my next comment also.

Comment: @HodofHod If something is flagged and then deleted, the flag disappears from the flag queue - there's no longer any need for mod attention.

Comment: @IsaacMoses. Ok, so that answers my question. It gets deleted from the queue and does not get marked "helpful" or contribute to flag weight. Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @HodofHod, I don't know if it affects flag weight or not.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I do. It doesn't affect it one way or the other. V'ha raya, my flag weight is unchanged and the flag, unmarked.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Hold that thought. I'm posting this as a bug because of several meta.SO posts.

Comment: Said bug posting is at http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/697.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug here; it *was* processing things that were "flagged for moderator attention" (i.e. bespoke messages), but it was not processing the spam/offensive flags. This is because back in the depths of time (before we explicitly tracked flag outcomes), such votes on **deleted** posts were ignored in the moderator-facing UIs. It looks this didn't get updated to explicitly process the outcomes when the community votes to delete a post.

This has been fixed in the code (and will be deployed next release, usually within a day), and I will try to apply the change retrospectively.